# Mysql column index value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with a field 'priority' as Integer.
This priority is initially set incrementally from 1 to number of records
(similar as auto_increment).

```
e.g.
Id    Priority
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

However, values of Priority can be changed, if I want to insert a new record
with existing priority. In case that new records holds Priority value 2,
current priorities are increased by 1.

```
e.g.
Id    Priority
1     1
2     3
3     4
4     2
```

In case I change existing priority with some other value, all records
with priority value higher than the changed one should be decreased,
so in table, priorities are always unique from 1 and above (no matter
of record auto_indexed Id field.

Currently, my solution is manual (with a Perl code, a replace all Priority values in proper manner).

Since I've learned Mysql long versions ago, and currently I use version 5.0,
I wonder if mysql has such feature for column to be automatically updated.

Comment: like any other "decent" database: [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: @MarcB: In MySQL updating the same table a trigger comes from  is not possible AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET @original = ?
    , @new = ?
    , priority 
        = IF(priority = @original
            , @new
            , priority 
                + IF(@original < @new, -1, 1)
            )
WHERE priority >= LEAST(@original, @new) 
  AND priority <= GREATEST(@original, @new)
;
```

This should work for **updates** of existing rows (updating the row you want to change, and all that will need shifted) if provided with parameters for current position and new one. However, if you have a uniqueness constraint on `priority`, it will almost certainly violate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do right then you can do this with a single query

```
UPDATE table SET priority=priority+1 WHERE priority > n
```